# How to use API path param in npm request & request-promise libraries

Tags: node.js, express, npm, request, request-promise

In my NodeJS/Express app, I have API implementation which calls another external API.
For this, I am using npm request & request-promise libraries

How can I call API's that has path parameter?

```
const express = require('express');
const router = express.Router();
const rp = require('request-promise');


router.post('employee/:id', (req, res) => {
    const id = req.params.id; // I dont know how to use this in request library
    handleRequest(req, res);
})


function handleRequest(req, res) {

  const id = req.params.id; // I dont know how to use this in request library options? 

  var options = {
    method: req.method,
    uri: 'http://api.anotherhost.com/external/'+ req.path,
    body: req.body,
    qs: req.query,
    json: true
  };

  rp(options)
    .then((success) => res.send(success))
    .catch((err) => res.status(err.statusCode).send(err.message));
}
```

https://github.com/request/request

https://www.npmjs.com/package/request-promise

**Update:-**

This code so far works fine for other calls without path parameter.

Answer (score 2):

Since request doesn't provide an option to add path parameters you have to format your request uri to include them, you can simply use string literals to do this:

```js
  const id = req.params.id;
  var options = {
    method: req.method,
    uri: `http://api.anotherhost.com/external/${id}`,
    body: req.body,
    qs: req.query,
    json: true
  };
```

Keep in mind you must verify that the id format is valid.